# Bulk update row values ASP.NET Core C# Console App

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I've got a console app which gets json data from an instagram url like so: [https://instagram.com/{profileName}"](https://instagram.com/%7BprofileName%7D%22)

So I need to query all the rows that have non-null instagram usernames, and then per row, do an IG look up via the public api to get the ig account id and update the respective db row.

I've got two pieces of sql code which does a select all from the table and outputs InstagramIds if they are null, and the other query is an update of the instagram ID based on the Instagram Username.

How would I go about doing a bulk search and update for every InstagramUsername in my db and add all the corresponding instagram Ids to it?

```
public static async Task<InstagramUser> ScrapeInstagram(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // create html document
                var htmlBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlBody);

                // select script tags
                var scripts = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/script");

                // preprocess result
                var uselessString = "window._sharedData = ";
                var scriptInnerText = scripts[0].InnerText
                    .Substring(uselessString.Length)
                    .Replace(";", "");

                // serialize objects and fetch the user data
                dynamic jsonStuff = JObject.Parse(scriptInnerText);
                dynamic userProfile = jsonStuff["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"];

                //Update database query 
                string connectionString = @"Server=MyProject-dev-db.cothtpanmcn7.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=UserApp;User Id=testadmin;Password=test123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trusted_Connection=False;";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    //select all users with null value 
                    SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select * from ApplicationUser where InstagramId is null");

                    //Updates InstagramID based from user input of instagramUsername
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update ApplicationUser Set InstagramId = '" + userProfile.id + "'" + "where Instagram =  '" + userProfile.username + "'", con);
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }

                // create an InstagramUser
                var instagramUser = new InstagramUser
                {
                    FullName = userProfile.full_name,
                    FollowerCount = userProfile.edge_followed_by.count,
                    FollowingCount = userProfile.edge_follow.count,
                    Id = userProfile.id,
                    url = url
                };
                return instagramUser;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"Something wrong happened {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase} - {response.RequestMessage}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Bulk Search" and "Bulk Update", the only bulk operation is a `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: So I'd have to do a individual search everytime to update each row in my table?

Comment: You can update multiple rows at the same time, but not in a Bulk Operation.

Comment: I know how to get all the instagramIDs which are null but I don't know how to loop through and do a search at the same time to update all of them

Comment: You wouldn't want to loop though, if you're doing this from a SQL perspective. YOu would use an `UPDATE` and a `JOIN` to your data with the new values. In psuedo terms: `UPDATE I SET instagramID = ND.NewID FROM dbo.Instagram I JOIN NewData ND ON {Some Joining Clause};`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

- Get all the users without InstagramId
- Loop through the users, and call the API
- Map the data from the API to ApplicationUser
- Create a Temp table in SQL Server
- Insert data in the Temp table (using bulk copy in my example)
- Use the temp table to join with ApplicationUser to update a large number of rows.

Kinda of pseudo code:

```
var applicationUsers = await GetAllApplicationUsersWithoutInstagramId(); // Get the records from the database
foreach(var user in applicationUsers)
{
   var instagramInfo = await GetInstagramInfo(user ); // Get the data from the API
   u.InstagramId = instagramInfo.Id;
   // Map other properties
});


using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   await con.OpenAsync();
   var transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
   // Create a temp table
   var cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE #NewData(InstagramUsername NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, InstagramId BIGINT NOT NULL  /*Other columns*/)", con, transaction);
   await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsycn();
   
   // Create a data table to use with the SqlBulkCopy
   var table = new DataTable();
   foreach (var applicationUser in applicationUsers)
   {
       var row = table.NewRow();
       row["InstagramUsername"] = applicationUser.Instagram;
       row["InstagramId "] = applicationUser.InstagramId;
       /*Other columns*/
       table.Rows.Add(row);
   }

   // Bulk insert the new data into the temp table
   using var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction)
   {
      DestinationTableName = "#NewData", 
      BulkCopyTimeout = 3600 // 1 hour 
   };
   await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(table);
   
   // Perform the update
   cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    UPDATE au 
       SET au.InstagramId = nd.InstagramId 
       /*Other columns*/
    FROM ApplicationUser  au
    INNER JOIN #NewData nd on au.Instagram = nd.InstagramUsername
   ", con,transaction);   
   await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
   
   await transaction.CommitAsync();
}
```

Comment: How does it know which instagram username maps to which Id?

Comment: You can do this, by using the primary key of the table or user the `Instagram` column, see updated answer.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism, so it's completely useless where. Running 8 SqlBulkCopy operations in parallel can easily lead to 1/8th performance as all of them conflict with each other, trying to use the same bandwidth on the network, same disk IO on the server. In the end *all connections* will try to update the same target, blocking each otherr

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a new table? this console app will only be used couple of times so I'm  not keen to change the database up for this reason

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the Paralle.ForEach, is not doing any data access on SQL Server, it's only there the handle the call to an external api.

Comment: @rey123 this answer has several problems, but the one thing it got right is that you need to get the data to the server and perform *one* UPDATE there. A temporary table gets deleted automatically once the connection closes, although it's better to have a permanent staging table, with adequate indexing, perhaps in a separate filegroup

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts which is not data parallelism either. In fact, this won't even wait for any response. That's essentially a call to multiple `async void` lambdas

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I'll give this a go and update you :)

Comment: @rey123 really don't. Definitely don't use `Parallel.ForEach`, next thing you'll be asking why no results are coming back

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos any other recommendations?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts how does this line work?        row["InstagramId "] = applicationUser.InstagramId;
 how can you get InstagramId from applicationUser?

Comment: You didn't share your model, but you could add a a nullable property on your applicationUser class, that you fill in with the data from the api.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public async Task<int> DeleteMultiple(int[] ids)
{
    return await _factoryRepository.BatchUpdateAsync
        (a => new Factory
        {
            IsDeleted = true;
        }, a => 
             ids.Contains(a.Id));
        });
}
```